# ZeroR Classifier

Tags: classification, predictive-modeling, weka

I've got a program that analyses some data based on a bunch of values then spits out a true/false value if it was correct or not. I'm using the Weka software to graph this all up and I just want to show the ROC curve for my data.

If I use the ZeroR classifier does it change the data in any way or does it just display the data?

I want to just show the results and get the ROC without changing/inferring any data - can I use ZeroR for this?

Comment: Can you include a link which explain what is a ZeroR classifier, please?  And, welcome to the site :)

Comment: I Want Complete tutorials with implementation. can i have any one help me plzzz.

Answer (score 1):

ZeroR classifier uses only the target (dependent variable) to build a majority classifier. As a consequence, it does not fit your purpose. You can built it from code as described here: [Generating ROC curve example](https://weka.wikispaces.com/Generating+ROC+curve). Basically you do not need a classifier, you need only the results and an instance of [ThresholdCurve](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/ThresholdCurve.html) class (this is how it is named in weka library).